# display() seems to only get called upon resize

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Basically, the rotation I've implemented only gets drawn to the screen during the screen being resized. To debug, I inserted a print in the display() function, outputting the angle. Upon running the program, this only shows output for 2 iterations of display(), and then again during any subsequent resizing of the screen.
This leads me to believe display() is only getting called twice? 
I've posted the relevant callbacks  below, but let me know if any other code is required.

```
float angle = 0.0f;
float increment = 0.5f;

@Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) 
    {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();      // get the OpenGL graphics context
        glu = new GLU();                         // get GL Utilities
        glut = new GLUT();
        gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // set background (clear) color

        gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);      // set clear depth value to farthest
        gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enables depth testing
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  // the type of depth test to do

        gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); // blends colors nicely, and smoothes out lighting

        calculateSpecks(noSpecks);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) 
    {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();  // get the OpenGL 2 graphics context
        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear color and depth buffers
        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        glu.gluLookAt(1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        gl.glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        angle+=increment;

        //setLighting(gl);
        glut.glutWireSphere(1, 32, 32);

        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        for(int i = 0; i < noSpecks; i++)
        {
            gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
                gl.glVertex3i(specks[i][0], specks[i][1], specks[i][2]);
            gl.glEnd();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) 
    {
          GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();  // get the OpenGL 2 graphics context

          if (height == 0) height = 1;   // prevent divide by zero
          float aspect = (float)width / height;

          // Set the view port (display area) to cover the entire window
          gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

          // Setup perspective projection, with aspect ratio matches viewport
          gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  // choose projection matrix
          gl.glLoadIdentity();             // reset projection matrix
          glu.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0); // fovy, aspect, zNear, zFar

          // Enable the model-view transform
          gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
          gl.glLoadIdentity(); // reset
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized, I had forgotten that the use of an animator is mandatory to drive the display() function in JOGL. Problem solved

Comment: It's not mandatory but it's a good practice in order to avoid reinventing the wheel. Some engines don't use an animator and directly call GLAutoDrawable.display() to run the GLEventListener instances: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GLAutoDrawable.html#display() If you use no animator and if you don't call GLAutoDrawable.display(), nothing will be rendered by JOGL. This method is called when the window or the canvas is realized or resized, which explains why it was called a few times before you added an animator into your code.